# AFNetworking send params as Application/text

Tags: ios, web-services, afnetworking, content-type

i have this requirement from the backend developer to send the parameters or content-type as Application/text , since AFnetworking sends the params as Form , the Backend is rejecting the request , i have tried changing the content type to Application/text by following line but doesn't seem to work ,

Try 1

```
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/text" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

Try 2

```
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/text" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

i don't know if AFNETWorking in converting the parameters to JSON , but i have check it isn't happening .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: it's already there , it's  a response serializer , the issue is in request serializer . when sending request params not when receiving response .